# 400 Bad Request when calling WCF service?

Tags: javascript, wcf, amcharts, windows-server-2003, http-status-code-400

I am debugging an html page with three javascript charts that each call two WCF services: one paints the map and the other plots points. There are six calls (two/map). This WCF service and the HTML are both published in the same local Windows 2003 server.

The top three calls in `Dev Tools` are the points plotted. The other three calls paint the map. The issue is that I'm getting a `400 Bad Request` in the last three calls. If I call them directly from a browser, they will return the correct JSON immediately.

[image]

This are the errors from one call:

```
Request URL: http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:89/Map.svc/GetWinner/9-19-2019/9-26-2019/0/0/ST
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: XX.XXX.XX.XX:89
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 1647
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 27 Sep 2019 21:29:03 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Provisional headers are shown
Origin: http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:93
Referer: http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:93/map.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
```

What can the issue be?

Comment: How do you design your JS code to make an invocation?
You HTTPGet request seems no problem. have you copied the URL to the browser address bar and check the result?

Comment: Do you mean call the WCF service directly in the browser? If so, then yes, and it returns the appropriate JSON.

Comment: May I see the code snippets of the last three Javascript invocations? 400 error indicates that either the requested address is wrong or that there is a problem with the request.

Comment: `Dev Tools` displays the `Request URL` with the 400 error. If I right-click the url and "open in new tab", I will receive the correct JSON.

Comment: I have no idea. wish the below link is useful to you. https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/400-bad-request/    Welcome to share with your workaround to this issue. thanks.